# Is it possible to show custom version label instead of regular Modified by label in version selector?

Tags: versions

I want to change the version name of an item, from 'Modified xx by xx' to something like 'Bonus Offer', to make each version name to be more specific. Is it possible to do it? Or it is 'out of the box'? If it's possible, could it go even further like add an edit button alongside each version?
Thanks, guys.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not simple. The dialog in your screenshot is located here:

```
{webroot}/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Manager/Galleries/Versions/Gallery Versions.xml
```

And the code beside is:

```
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions.GalleryVersionsForm,Sitecore.Client
```

To change this, you would need to create your own code beside file and change the `.xml` file to point at your new code beside. Then modify the `OnLoad` handler in your code beside to get the content you want.

Currently the OOTB version is doing this for each version:

```
Item[] versions = currentItem.Versions.GetVersions();
for (int index = versions.Length - 1; index >= 0; --index)
{
    Item obj = versions[index];
    XmlControl control = ControlFactory.GetControl("Gallery.Versions.Option") as XmlControl;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) control, typeof (XmlControl), "Xml Control \"{0}\" not found", "Gallery.Versions.Option");
    Context.ClientPage.AddControl((System.Web.UI.Control) this.Versions, (System.Web.UI.Control) control);
    CultureInfo culture = Context.User.Profile.Culture;
    string str1 = obj.Statistics.Updated == DateTime.MinValue ? Translate.Text("[Not set]") : DateUtil.FormatShortDateTime(DateUtil.ToServerTime(obj.Statistics.Updated), culture);
    string str2 = obj.Statistics.UpdatedBy.Length == 0 ? "-" : obj.Statistics.UpdatedBy;
    string str3 = obj.Version.ToString() + ".";
    string str4 = obj.Version.Number != currentItem.Version.Number ? "<div class=\"versionNum\">" + str3 + "</div>" : "<div class=\"versionNumSelected\">" + str3 + "</div>";
    control["Number"] = (object) str4;
    control["Header"] = (object) Translate.Text("Modified <b>{0}</b> by <b>{1}</b>.", (object) str1, (object) str2);
    control["Click"] = (object) string.Format("item:load(id={0},language={1},version={2})", (object) currentItem.ID, (object) currentItem.Language, (object) obj.Version.Number);
}
```

I'm not sure where you are storing the descriptions of your versions. Maybe you could add a versioned field to your base page or item template that contains that description and your content editors can update that each time they create a new version? Then you would be able to use that in the code above.

There are caveats tho - this would require changing an OOTB file to point at your new `CodeBeside` file, so anytime there is an upgrade, you may have to replicate that change.